How to fix 'Cannot find namespace 'THREE'' in vagran/dxf-viewer lib?
I am trying to use vagran/dxf-viewer with angular 16 project. I get error when launching project with ng serve command. All I did is just installed packages and added import to component. I was trying to change 'module' prop to 'commonjs' and 'esnext' in tsconfig.js file, but it does not help. How to fix it ? Stackblitz example
Error:
Error: node_modules/dxf-viewer/src/index.d.ts:80:12 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'THREE'. 80     base?: THREE.Vector2

Import: import { DxfViewer } from "dxf-viewer"; import * as THREE from 'three';

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens

Import this - import * as THREE from 'three';

@NarenMurali Hello, I added stackblitz example in message.

@TigerResource Hello, I added this import it not solved problem.

Please add the relevant code inside the question as well

@DarkBee Hello, stackblitz example added to question.

Your code should also be included inside the question. If that link disappears then your question is not valid anymore - [ask]
